# setting a valid value for textbox

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2005, textbox

I am creating a program and I want to restrict a string to be inserted to my `Database` can someone tell me how to do it?

as of now here is my codes:

```
 Dim SQLcon As New SqlConnection
        Dim SQLdr As SqlDataReader
        Try
            SQLcon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=#### ;Initial Catalog=####;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=####;Password=####"
            Dim SQLcmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.Patients" & _
                                         "(pIDNo,pLName,pFName,pMI,pSex,pStatus,pTelNo,pDocID,pAddr,pStreet,pBarangay,pCity,pProvince,pLNameKIN,pFNameKIN,pMIKIN,pRelationKIN,pTotalDue)" & _
                                         "VALUES(@pIDNo,@pLName,@pFName,@pMI,@pSex,@pStatus,@pTelNo,@pDocID,@pAddr,@pStreet,@pBarangay,@pCity,@pProvince,@pLNameKIN,@pFNameKIN,@pMIKIN,@pRelationKIN,@totaldue)", SQLcon)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pIDNo", txtPNumber.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pLName", txtLname.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pFName", txtFname.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pMI", txtMI.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pSex", txtPatientSex.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pStatus", txtStatus.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pTelNo", txtPatientTelNo.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pDocID", txtPatientDoctor.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pAddr", txtStreetNumber.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pStreet", txtStreetName.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pBarangay", txtBarangay.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pCity", txtCity.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pProvince", txtProvince.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pLnameKIN", txtKinLname.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pFnameKIN", txtKinFname.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pMIKIN", txtKinMI.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pRelationKIN", txtRelationToPatient.Text)
            SQLcmd.Parameters.Add("@totaldue", SqlDbType.Money).Value = Decimal.Parse(txtTotalDue.Text)
            SQLcon.Open()
            MsgBox("Patient Added!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            SQLdr = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured, Can't Add Patient!" & ex.Message)
        Finally
            SQLcon.Close()
        End Try
        Return ""
```

in the `txtSex.Text`

I only want the user to input only 'M' for Male and 'F' for Female

in the `txtStatus.Text`

I only want the user to input only 'S' for Single, 'M' for Married, 'W' for Widow, 'H' for Separated

one more thing :

in `txtMI` and `txtMIKIN` is it possible to do a conversion after the user input a value?

Example :

if the user input 'a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m, .......' as his/her middle initial it will automatically inserted as 'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M, ......' in my `Database`

Comment: You should use a `ComboBox` instead of a `TextBox`. It will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: but it's not necessary for middle inital because sometimes some people have 2 M.I. , and my boss says that I can only use textbox...

Comment: I don't know what exactly you needed, but what I know, I always use `combobox` for something that exact option as your answer. First, to avoid the typo from the user, so all result from user would be standart when we inserting to database, second, to helping user from re-type all the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since about `combobox` had been answered.

I would like to answer about to change to [UPPERCASE](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312897).

You can use these kind of code.

way #1

```
Dim upper as string = (txtMI.text.ToUpper())
```

way #2

```
Dim upper as string = (UCase(txtMI.text))
```

way #3

```
Dim upper as string = (StrConv(txtMI.text,VbStrConv.UpperCase))
```

Comment: lemme try this one sir kolonel :)

Comment: where should I put these codes? I'm having a trouble here >.<

Comment: You can initialize on the top on your code like usual and just put `upper = (txtMI.text.ToUpper())` or the 2 else. The way it work was to convert you value from your `txtMI` textbox into an uppercase and save it to variable called upper (optional name). When you want inserting to database, called the `upper` not the `txtMI.text` anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You are inserting data, so you need to call:

```
SQLcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

rather than

```
SQLcmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: Value of type 'Integer'  cannot be converted to 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand'

Comment: I'm not saying that your answer is wrong i'm just posting the error that just display on my screen and I post it here, because I don't know how to fix it ... >.<

Comment: The problem with using AddWithValue() is it might make the wrong choice. Be more explicit with your datatypes: use Add()

Answer (score 0):

```
txtMI.Text = StrConv(txtMI.Text, VbStrConv.Uppercase) this codes solve my problem...
```